# Flutter app running with error throwWithStackTrace

Tags: flutter

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:14:11: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:17:9: Error: Member not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
Error.throwWithStackTrace(

```
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:12:7: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
^